# Why can batteries store much more energy than capacitors even though they are much smaller?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, capacitance, battery-chemistry

Why are batteries significantly smaller than capacitors yet can store much more energy ?

Comment: batteries use chemistry, capacitors use elasticity (on a molecular scale)  -- might get a better answer in physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jasen Yes, or if it's chemistry related as you say, i could try chemistry.stackexchange.com, but i think many electronics enthusiasts have often wondered about this, as i have. and this is why i asked it here first.

Comment: Why can capacitors form a tuned circuit with an inductor yet batteries can't. Why can you apply a reverse voltage to non-electrolytic capacitor yet doing so to a battery will harm it? Why can you apply any (reasonable) voltage to a capacitor but not to a battery? They are **different** things. It's like asking why your car cannot fly but aeroplanes can.

Comment: if you want a detailed explanation ask in chemistry or physics.  mostly you can do electronics with only the understanding of how devices behave, not needing the details of how they work.  eg: we use *conventional current*

Comment: @Andyaka Both capacitors and batteries share the similar characteristics of storing charge, and that was the only thing i was referring to. as for the car and airplane analogy, since they both share the characteristics of "moving forward", if i would have asked "why do airplanes move forward faster than cars" that would be a legitimate question.

Comment: To expand on Jasen's comment (since I didn't answer fast enough) consider a model aeroplane can be powered by elasticicity (a rubberband) or chemistry (a small piston engine). The latter is considerably more powerful.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes that makes more intuitive sense, and should have been added as an answer.

Comment: Capacitors store energy by twisting electron orbits of fixed atoms or molecules. Batteries store energy by **moving** atoms or molecules.